# Build project with "experimental/filesystem" using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, c++14

I need to add a "experimental/filesystem" header to my project

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
int main() {
    auto path = std::experimental::filesystem::current_path();
    return 0;
}
```

So I used -lstdc++fs flag and linked with libstdc++fs.a

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(testcpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14 -lstdc++fs" )
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++fs.a)
add_executable(testcpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

However, I have next error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_link_libraries):   Cannot
>   specify link libraries for target "testcpp" which is not built by
>   this project.

But if I compile directly, it`s OK:

```
g++-7 -std=c++14 -lstdc++fs  -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++-7 -o main main.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++fs.a
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's just that the `target_link_libraries()` call has to come after the `add_executable()` call. Otherwise the `testcpp` target is not known yet. CMake parses everything sequential.

So just for completeness, here is a working version of your example I've tested:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(testcpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# NOTE: The following would add library with absolute path
#       Which is bad for your projects cross-platform capabilities
#       Just let the linker search for it
#add_library(stdc++fs UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
#set_property(TARGET stdc++fs PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++fs.a")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(testcpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} stdc++fs)
```

Comment: This can't be right. Surely we're not supposed to hard-code library locations like that.

Comment: @einpoklum You are right. I just optimized the given code in the question a little (and omitted that part). I'll update my answer later today to search for the library.