# What is the correct way to link C++17 filesystem with CMake?

Tags: cmake, c++17, linker-errors

I noticed that linking my CMake project with gcc 8.3 fails to link functions from std::filesystem. This is not the case with gcc 9, clang 7 or clang 8.

I found solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476810/build-project-with-experimental-filesystem-using-cmake) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290254/problem-adding-stdfilesystem-to-cmake-project), but these hard-code the linking of `stdc++fs`, which is normally not what you want to do.

- So what is the correct way to link such libraries?
- Do I have to do a `find_package`? What would be the package I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no proper solution to this as of now. There still is an [open issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17834) on this subject on the CMake tracker.

Some seem to be using find modules like [this one](https://github.com/lethal-guitar/RigelEngine/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindFilesystem.cmake), which would allow you to use code like the following:

```
find_package(Filesystem REQUIRED)

add_executable(myapp myapp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE std::filesystem)
```

In my opinion this is preferable to changing `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` or linking against `stdc++fs` directly.