# CMake idiom for overcoming libstdc++ filesystem weirdness?

Tags: cmake, c++14, linker-errors, libstdc++, std-filesystem

If you build C++14 code with G++ and libstdc++, there's a library named `libstdc++fs`, which is separate from the rest of `libstdc++`, and contains the code for `std::experimental::filesystem`. If you don't link against it, you'll get undefined references.

The "trick" I'm using for overcoming this right now is:

```
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
        set(CXX_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES "stdc++fs")
endif()
```

and later:

```
target_link_libraries(my_target PUBLIC ${CXX_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES})
```

but - I don't like having to place this code in every project I work on. Is there a simpler or more standard idiom I could use? Some way this will all happen implicitly perhaps, with some CMake behind-the-scences magic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476810/build-project-with-experimental-filesystem-using-cmake

Comment: cmake open issue: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17834

Comment: @Pedro: This is not a dupe, although it's related. I am already implementing the solution to that question, I just don't like it and want something better.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: Nothing right now, wait for a newer CMake version**

As @Pedro graciously points out, this is a known problem, and there is an [open issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17834) about it at KitWare's GitLab site for CMake:

> #### Portable linking for C++17 std::filesystem
>
> If using `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17` and `std::filesystem`, GCC requires linking of an extra library: `stdc++fs`.  ... If C++17 is enabled, would it be worth automatically linking to stdc++fs for GCC versions which require this?  Likewise for any quirks in other compilers or libraries.

The KitWare issue is about C++17, for which apparently you still need the separate extra library (i.e. it's not just because of the "experimentality" in C++14). Hopefully we'll see some traction on this matter - but

Note: If you're experiencing this problem with C++17's `std::filesystem`, you're in luck - that code is built into `libstdc++` beginning with GCC 9, so if you're using g++ 9 or later, and `std::filesystem`, you should no longer experience this problem.

Comment: Exactly. If you are using an experimental feature, it is not extraordinary to depend on some special or unusual buildsystem solutions. When the experimental feature becomes mainstream, those unusual workarounds are no longer required.

Comment: [GCC implementation status](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017). c++11 is not yet complete right now in 2020.

Comment: _"Luckily, libstdc++fs was merged into libstdc++ for GCC 9"_, not entirely true. The C++17 `std::filesystem` symbols were merged into `libstdc++.so` but the `std::experimental::filesystem` ones are still in the separate `libstdc++fs.a` library, and will stay there.

Comment: @Pedro, C++11 is complete apart from a couple of minor things that nobody seems to care about. C++14 is complete. C++17 is only missing one tiny feature and one fairly large one.

Comment: @Pedro: Why is the C++11 implementation status relevant here?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Edited to reflect your note. You could have edited yourself, BTW - you are welcome to edit my posts whenever you feel like it.